# How to run multiple tasks upon launch in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have the following launch task in launch.json:

```
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/MyProject.dll",

            [...]
```

I would also like to run npm run start:dev, when launching, and terminate it when stopping. So I added this:

```
    {
        "command": "npm run start:dev",
        "name": "Run npm start:dev",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/ClientApp",
    }
```

But the latter doesn't do anything. Is it possible to run `npm run start:dev` upon launch together with an MVC Core app?

Comment: the `preLaunchTask` should be the `name` of the task: `"Run npm start:dev"`, or `${defaultBuildTask}`

Comment: @rioV8 I'm not exactly sure what you mean? :) The npm run start:dev can't be a pre launch task, because it observes files and will never finish.

Comment: if it is a watch task why stop it? create a version that builds and does not watch. `build` is not a task name so not valid for `preLaunchTask`